# iOS 7 Sprite Kit change zPosition in SKAction

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

I have two different `SKSpriteNodes`. The first is stationary and the second, I would like, to move around the first node. I have my second node is flying in from off screen with a `zPosition` of 11 (the first node has a `zPosition` of 10). When the second node flies to the opposite end of the screen, I have the node flip and fly back across. At this time I would like to change the `zPosition` to 9.

```
witch.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width + 200, self.size.height / 2 + 50);
witch.zPosition = 11;
[self addChild:witch];

SKAction *moveLeft = [SKAction moveToX:-200 duration:8];
SKAction *moveRight = [SKAction moveToX:self.size.width + 200 duration:8];
SKAction *moveDown = [SKAction moveToY:secondNode.position.y - 50 duration:0.3];
SKAction *moveUp = [SKAction moveToY:secondNode.position.y + 50 duration:0.3];
SKAction *flipRight = [SKAction scaleXTo:-1 duration:0];
SKAction *flipLeft = [SKAction scaleXTo:1 duration:0];
[secondNode runAction:
  [SKAction repeatActionForever:
      [SKAction sequence:
         @[moveLeft, moveDown, flipRight, CHANGEZPOSITIONHERE, moveRight, moveUp, flipLeft, CHANGEZPOSITIONHERE]]]];
```

How would I go about changing the `zPosition` in the middle of an `SKAction`?

Thank you in advance for all suggestions and help.

Comment: use the runBlock: action

Comment: Of course, thank you. If you answer the question I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was found due to LearnCocos2D comment.

Adding a runBlock:action I was able to change the zPosition. The final code is:

```
[secondNode runAction:
 [SKAction repeatActionForever:
  [SKAction sequence:
     @[moveLeft, moveDown, flipRight, 
         [SKAction runBlock:(dispatch_block_t)^(){
               secondNode.zPosition = 9;
          }], moveRight, moveUp, flipLeft, 
         [SKAction runBlock:(dispatch_block_t)^(){
               secondNode.zPosition = 11;
          }]]]]];
```